# pymongo cursor taking long time to find

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo-3.x

Pymongo cursor taking ~ 2 seconds, please suggest ways to optimize below query.

**Facts of query**

```
Records in MongoDB : 120,000
Indexed Key: emp_id
MongoDB Server: 3.2.11
PyMongo       : 3.5
Python        : 2.7
```

**Cursor**

To find a document from db, by using indexed field as filter and projecting only required fields, its consuming ~2 Seconds.

I am looking for ways to optimize this query so that it can be faster.

```
db = client["db_name"]
user_data = db.collection_name.find_one(
    {"emp_id": 1234}, {'nameFirst': 1, 'nameLast': 1, 'emp_id': 1, }
)
```

Elapsed Time: 1.829226017

---

For Informational purpose, please refer same query using find()

```
def query_cursor():
    db = client["db_name"]
    cursor = db.collection_name.find(
        {"emp_id": 1234}, {'nameFirst': 1, 'nameLast': 1, 'emp_id': 1, }
    ).limit(1)

    return cursor

def get_user_data():
    cursor = query_user_data()
    user_data = None
    for document in cursor:
        user_data = document
    return user_data

print(get_user_data())
```

Elapsed Time for query_cursor: 0.00215888023376

Elapsed Time for get_user_data: 1.79128599167

Comment: From your query, it seems as if it would return data fairly quickly. So your calculation is probably including the overhead of creating the initial connection to the database. Where are your database & the computer/server that you're running the code situated in relation to one another?

Comment: @justcompile I finally switched datacenter and was able to run it faster. Now its around 0.10 Seconds.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Issue resolved after switching to correct data center. Now the DB query works super fast and its less than 0.10 Seconds.